# Organizing columms in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, virtual-field

I am using QGIS 3.14. I want to organize my columns in the attribute table but I cant change the virtual fields columns place.

It is always last. Can I put it between two non-virtual fields columns?

Comment: you can use a virtual layer and in the select statement you can reorder the fields like "select column1, virtualcol1, column2, virtualcol2, column3 from mylayer"

Comment: Thank you eurojam, but why can't I change it in my original layer? I dont want to work on another layer

Comment: You can not do this for the original layer. You have to save the layer doing a 'Refractor Fields' to a new layer. This will change your virtual columns to physical columns. Or do like eurojam says make a virtual layer, or just live with you virtual column being last.

Comment: Thank you jacob. You are right. Sometimes you just have to accept being last...:)

Comment: Am I missing something here? You want to reorder the attributes columns and you can't? Did you use the organize column by right clicking the columns and draging each column to the desired position?

Comment: Yes I did. It doea not work on virtual fields

Comment: I've just tried it with the right click (QGIS3.12) and I could reorder the columns including a virtual field, like proposed from geoSAM

Comment: Did it change the order in the table itself or just in the "Organize table" window?

Comment: Ok it seems to work just fine on 3.12 version ltr. Just like you said.  Maybe somerhing is diffrent in the PI 3.14. Thank you all  for your help

Comment: I just tried it in QGIS 3.14 and it worked. It's a way to organize the columns only in the project you are working at. To make this permanent you should use the refactor fields tool.

Comment: I cant change the order in 3.14 nor 3.10. I dont know why

Comment: @YuvalM Please [edit] your question to include any additional details and any responses to comments.  Comments are for people to request additional information or clarification, your response should be as an [edit] to your question.